# How to make google reCaptcha mandatory on contactus page

Tags: magento-1.9, contact-us, form-validation, captcha

I have set up google reCaptcha on contact us page but i dont know how to check its mandatory on submit for any other way.

Comment: This script use for validation google reCaptcha like a default validation of magento. please use it. [Click here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/183491/how-to-validate-the-google-recaptcha/221567#221567)

Comment: Try https://magecomp.com/magento-new-recaptcha.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do so, you need some custom code, please follow below steps which work for me:

> Note: I assume you used **jQuery** library on your frontend theme

**Step-1**: On document ready add some custom class to your `reCAPTCHA` input field:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#recaptcha_response_field').addClass('required-captcha-entry');
})
</script>
```

**Step-2**: Initialize `Magento` `VarienForm` javascript class object and add new validation rule for `reCAPTCHA` field:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var yourFormValidationObj = new VarienForm('your_form_id');

Validation.add('required-captcha-entry', ' ', function(v) {
    return !Validation.get('IsEmpty').test(v);
})
</script>
```

**Step-3**: On form submit, validate form for required values

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if(yourFormValidationObj.validator.validate()){
    // Form validate and ready to submit
    jQuery('YOUR_FORM_IDENTIFIER').submit();
} 
</script>
```

That's, your `reCAPTCHA` field is become required field and validated before submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method:
[Magento Enable Captcha For Contact Us Form](http://www.magentostack.com/magento-enable-captcha-for-contact-us-form/)

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Sorry I am using Google captcha .

Comment: Are you using reCaptcha Extension?

Comment: Not extension i am customize and used this.

Comment: you can use this extension [reCAPTCHA](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/recaptcha-1.html) and its free

Comment: i have try this but not working form e. not display captcha box. i have already set the both key.

Comment: tell me about your environment, you are on localhost or live server?

Comment: you can your issue on [this](https://github.com/StudioForty9/Recaptcha/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=) releated to extension

Comment: live. magento 1.9.0.1 CE

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37547/discussion-between-umar-ali-and-ajay-patel).

Comment: https://github.com/ProxiBlue/reCaptcha see the readme for instructions for contactus and reviews activation of recaptcha. Simply just works.